# Is there a listener for PDFAnnotation?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there some way to listen for text updates for PDFAnnotations?

We can use `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(awesomeTest), name: .PDFViewAnnotationHit, object: nil)` to get the active annotation but I can't seem to find a good way way to "listen" for updates. Right now I'm left with polling `annotation.widgetStringValue` from a timer. Any suggestions?

Would also be nice to know where the cursor is and what text is positioned to left and right sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to wrap this up. I ended up implementing my own editable view on top of the annotation instead. This gives me all the freedom I need with just some minor hasle removing and opening it at the right times.